# How to get/view/read the current URL is in Safari?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, url

Did lots of searching, just came up with the "how to open a URL in Safari..."

Looking to find how to get/view/read what the current URL is when Safari is opened.

Edit:
My app opens a URL with Safari as follows:

```
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:myURL]];
```

Supposidly, after some validation from website, the ending URL has some attached info.
So I'm trying to get that final URL from Safari.

Comment: Do you mean in a `UIWebView` instance or the Safari app?

Comment: @RichardBrown Sorry... Safari app.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible, you do not have access to any outside app. However how most of these authentication / validation techniques work is (like facebook / dropbox login etc.) is that they use some kind of callback back to the app.

You can register an specific url scheme to your app which can have parameters, this way you can get the info in the url the you need. The website will need to support callbacks though or you would need to be able to access the website to provide it yourself.

On how to work with URL schemes you can check out this tutorial:

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-working-with-url-schemes/

Comment: It's never 'impossible'. It's probably stored in a plist somewhere if you really want to go digging for it. Of course, that type of digging will get your app banned from the app-store...

Comment: If this is not possible, then I must be mis-interpreting what is suppose to happen.  I'll go back research on it.  Thanks

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: Due to sandboxing, it probably *is* impossible.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot view this information, as the other posters have said. What you need to do is to use your own website to match the user of the app to the user on the website.

For example, you can send a random number to your website when the user is sent there buy.php?id=123445. Then request (periodically and/or with a button press) via the iPhone the result from your website ex. check.php?id=123445.

This also could be done with cookies and php sessions.